# Jquery adding steps like on instructables.com

Tags: jquery

If you go to http://www.instructables.com/ then click on Create->Step by step and as you click "Add step" it adds another step on top of the page and loads that new form. I would like to duplicate that functionality... Can someone point me to the correct direction?

Comment: That's not how this site works. You do the research. Come back for some help if you come across a **specific** problem whilst implementing your findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of your Steps you may want to use something more geared for this than jQuery, Take a look at [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/), [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), and [Angularjs](http://angularjs.org/). There are a lot of different frameworks out there that make this kind of thing very easy to do and subsequently maintain. These are just a few of the better known ones in my opinion.

That being said you can do this with jQuery, however the code will become very difficult to implement and maintain as your site grows in complexity. If you are dead set on using Jquery there are plenty of tutorials out there, take a look at the [JQuery API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/), which will give you a very good starting point on how to accomplish what you want. But for further help post code that you have tried, which you are having trouble with. That will get you far more help than your current question.